# Trigger avoid inserting duplicates

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have created a `trigger` when a value is inserted to the main table `dbo.MVF_Transport_Register`, it updtes the `dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc` table with that record. Also when a value is changed on the main table `dbo.MVF_Transport_Register` it updates the particular field value accordingly on the other `dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc`.

Problem I have is: my trigger inserts duplicate records into the `dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc` table.

How can I amend this trigger so it checks `dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc` to see if the record exsists before inserting the record. If the record exists, it shouldn't insert duplicate records.

Can some one please check my trigger an advice how to sort this thanks in advance big help

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTransport]
ON [dbo].[MVF_Transport_Register]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE c 
    SET c.Record_Status = i.Record_status
    FROM MVF_SYSTEMS.dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc AS c
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON c.Order_No = i.Order_No
                             AND c.Record_Status <> i.Record_Status 
    WHERE i.Record_Status IN ('CONFIRMED', 'AMENDED')
      AND i.Price > 0;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MVF_SYSTEMS.dbo.MVF_Transport_Acc ([Order_No], [Record_Status], [Notes], [Transport_Supplier], 
                    [Surcharge], [Vendor_No], [Pallets], [Amend_Pallets],[Price], 
                    [Input_Date], [Amend_Price], [Transport_Invoice_No],[Transport_Job_No], 
                    [Amend_Date], [Report_Price], [Return_Price], [Report_Date])
            SELECT 
                i.[Order_No], i.[Record_Status], i.[Notes], i.[Transport_Supplier], 
                i.[Surcharge], i.[Vendor_No], i.[Pallets], i.[Amend_Pallets], i.[Price], 
                i.[Input_Date], i.[Amend_Price], i.[Transport_Invoice_No], i.[Transport_Job_No], 
                i.[Amend_Date], i.[Report_Price], i.[Return_Price], i.[Report_Date]
            FROM 
                inserted AS i
            WHERE 
                i.Record_Status IN ('CONFIRMED', 'AMENDED')
                AND i.Price > 0;
      END
END
```

Comment: Which dbms?  Your trigger is firing after an update, not before.  It sounds like you want an instead-of trigger (if MSSQL).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I am usin MSSQL

Comment: Added the relevant `sql-server` tag to make clear which RDBMS is being used (since triggers are **highly** vendor specific)